# Java run shell command mysql with sed

Tags: java, mysql, shell

I have a shell command (mysql) and I'm having problems on how to run it in java using getruntime:

```
sql=$(mysql -u cactiuser -ppassword cacti -s -N -e "select name_cache, name from data_template_data where  data_source_path=\"<path_rra>/test.rrd\";" | sed 's/\t/,/g')
```

Java:

```
String command = "<sql above>";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

The shell command is quite complicated as it has sed and I don't know how to segregate them properly to run in getruntime.  Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a jdbc connection to mysql. Forget calling a shell script for that, is ugly and greatly unefficient.

More info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Once you have the data, you can edit it in java code, not sed.